# Regex stop at first occurence

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have this:

```
Something Something Something Something111
Something Something Something Something
Something Something Something Something222.
Something Something Something Something
Something Something Something Something333.
```

I need to start from Something111 and stop after the first occurence of "."

Right now i have this code:

```
(?<=Something111)((.|\n)*)\.
```

Which is returning all before the last "." so in this case all after "Something333"

But i need to stop after the first "." so in this case after "Something222"

So the returned text should be this:

```
Something Something Something Something111
Something Something Something Something
Something Something Something Something222.
```

I am working in UiPath Studio which uses VB.NET as language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you also want to include what is before you don't need the positive lookbehind because if you use `(?<=Something111)` then that will not be part of the match.

Instead you could match from the start of the string `^` and match `Something111` between word boundaries `\b`.

After that, match any char except a dot using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated).

```
^.*\bSomething111\b[^.]*\.
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aRpRuW/1)